# Render particular block instead of complete layout

Tags: layout, magento-1.8, render

If we call the below code in a controller, it renders the complete layout handle related to the controller.

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

But what I want is to render only a particular block from the layout handle.

Lets say if my layout handle has a child block with name "hello", I want to render that particular block. How to do this?

I tried the below code:

```
    $this->loadLayout();
    $layout = $this->getLayout();
    $block = $layout->getBlock("hello");
    $block->renderLayout(); /* Error: 503 Service Unavailable */
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$layout = $this->getLayout();
$block = $layout->getBlock("hello");
echo $block->toHtml();
```

For ajax requests do this:

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
```

Comment: I am trying to do this on ajax request. If I do as you mentioned above, the responseText is coming blank..

Comment: Hey wait I forgot adding `echo`. working fine now.. thanks :)

Comment: @Mr_Green I've updated the answer with the best practice for ajax calls.